# Is "How's it going" a slang saying

Tags: slang

My friend asked me how's it going and I asked how's what going  as I expected the friends meaning was that of knowing what I was currently doing but my friend doesn't know currently the things which I'm doing

Is "How's it going" a slang saying

Comment: In common use it means roughly the same as "How are you doing?"

Comment: No, it is not slang.

Answer (score -1):

**how's it going**  [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/79544?redirectedFrom=how%27s%20it%20going#eid1178539000)

> (b) colloquial. how's it going?: used to ask a person how he or she
>   is getting on, or to enquire whether a particular project or event is
>   proceeding well. Also used as a greeting: ‘how are you doing?’, ‘how's
>   life?’.

Yes it could be considered slang.  As in:

> 2013   L. Miller Parallel    ‘Hey, honey! How's it going? Having fun?’
>   ‘Yep!’ I enthuse, trying to sound upbeat.

**How goes it?** is idiomatic too.  *Hey, Tom! How goes it?*

Comment: Slang is typically characterized by an association between a word or phrase and a culture or group of people. This expression is lacking in that regard.